# Solr plugin for altering and adding synonyms to synonyms.txt

Tags: plugins, solr, solrnet, solr4

Im searching for a Solr plugin for altering and adding synonyms to synonyms.txt?

Is there such a thing out there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'adding synonyms to synonyms.txt'. However, if you're looking at adding synonyms while you index, those synonyms are usually taken from synonyms.txt (whatever you name)

Here's an out of the box feature to perform the same.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory

```
    <fieldtype name="syn" class="solr.TextField">
       <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="syn.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
       </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been hunting this for a while as well.
No luck yet though.

I guess the main trouble in making a generally functional plugin for this would be filerights?